# Error in pom.xml while adding all dependencies and plug ins

Tags: java, plugins, while-loop, maven-2, pom.xml

Getting this error in pom.xml while adding all dependencies and plug ins. Trying to install cucumber.

```
Malformed POM C:\Users\swat\eclipse-workspace\cucumberframework\pom.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...org/POM/3.6.3; http://
 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.6.3.xsd">\r\n <m... @5:5)
```

TIA.

Comment: Clearly there is an error in that POM file.  But unless you show us the relevant part of it, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: You need to provide the POM file.